# Python: Why is my Except Block running when it isn't even true?

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I have a try-except block:

```
YourSecondPick = input("Second Card:");

try:
    if(int(YourSecondPick) not in YourHand):
        print("\nYou don't have that card.");
        return Main(40);
    else:
        YourTotalPick = int(YourFirstPick) + int(YourSecondPick);
        print("\nYou put down a total of {0}".format(YourTotalPick));
        YourHand.remove(int(YourFirstPick));
        YourHand.remove(int(YourSecondPick));
        YourHand.append(Deck.pop(random.choice(range(len(Deck)))));
        YourHand.append(Deck.pop(random.choice(range(len(Deck)))));
        return Main(45);
except ValueError as e:
    print("\nThe input you entered is not a number");
    print(e);
    return Main(40);
```

If you enter two cards in your hand, let's say 15 30 for example, it is supposed add the sum of these cards and put them into a new list. Then it will remove the cards from your and give you two more cards that are from the deck. Once this happens, it should return to the next block:

```
if(line == 45):
    while(len(Deck) / NumberOfPlayers >= 1):
            if(OneCard and Computer1 == True):
                Computer1Pick = (random.choice(Computer1Hand));
                print("Computer1 put down a {0}".format(Computer1Pick));
                MaxList.append(Computer1Pick);
                Computer1Hand.remove(int(Computer1Pick));
                Computer1Hand.append(Deck.pop(random.choice(range(len(Deck)))));

            elif(TwoCards and Computer1 == True):
                Computer1FirstPick = (random.choice(Computer1Hand));
                Computer1SecondPick = (random.choice(Computer1Hand));
                Computer1TotalPick = int(Computer1FirstPick) + int(Computer1SecondPick);
                print("Computer1 put down a total of {0}".format(Computer1TotalPick));
                MaxList.append(Computer1TotalPick);
                Computer1Hand.remove(int(Computer1FirstPick));
                Computer1Hand.remove(int(Computer1SecondPick));
                Computer1Hand.append(Deck.pop(random.choice(range(len(Deck)))));
                Computer1Hand.append(Deck.pop(random.choice(range(len(Deck)))));

            else:
                Computer1Pick = None;

            if(OneCard and Computer2 == True):
                Computer2Pick = (random.choice(Computer2Hand));
                print("Computer2 put down a {0}".format(Computer2Pick));
                MaxList.append(Computer2Pick);
                Computer2Hand.remove(int(Computer2Pick));
                Computer2Hand.append(Deck.pop(random.choice(range(len(Deck)))));

            else:
                Computer2Pick = None;

            if(OneCard and Computer3 == True):
                Computer3Pick = (random.choice(Computer3Hand));
                print("Computer3 put down a {0}".format(Computer3Pick));
                MaxList.append(Computer3Pick);
                Computer3Hand.remove(int(Computer3Pick));
                Computer3Hand.append(Deck.pop(random.choice(range(len(Deck)))));

            else:
                Computer3Pick = None;
            return Main(50);
```

Two problems arise in this code. One; the try-except block will always post the except even if you entered the data correctly. Two; the next block of code won't occur even though I put `return Main(45);`. I don't know why this is happening but I think it might have to do with how my code is setup. If you could tell me why this is happening and what I should do to improve upon this, I will be truly appreciative. I don't know what exactly is causing but I have a hunch that it's the  `Main(#)` parts. Here is what happens when I run it.

```
Your cards: [48, 50, 39, 83, 73]

Choose a number from your hand or enter a command.

First Card: 48
Second Card: 50

You put down a total of 98
Computer1 put down a total of 164

The input you entered is not a number

max() arg is an empty sequence

Your cards: [39, 83, 73, 18, 17]

Choose a number from your hand or enter a command.

First Card:
```

Even though `48` and `50` are apart of the list, it still wants to stay in the try-except block. If you can't find the problem here, click this link [Repl.it Code](https://repl.it/GOq6/731). This will take you to the full code.

Comment: You should really try to keep the `try except` to wrapping the minimal amount of code possible.

Comment: "One; the try-except block will always post the except even if you entered the data incorrectly" - that's when it's *supposed* to enter the `except` case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you think that they can find the problem with the try catch block alone? I am very catious when it comes to code. I want to make sure people have enough information to solve the problem. I might delete but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Also ifyou are going to just dump a bunch of code, you should at least try to stick with Python style conventions, e.g. variable names in `snake_case` instead of `UpperCase` (which in Python is used for class names). Not wrapping your conditions in extraneous parentheses, not ending lines with semi-colons... No one wants to read and decipher this.

Comment: What the heck is up with all those `return Main(whatever)` lines? It looks like you wrote this with `goto` and then tried to convert it to tail recursion.

Comment: @user2357112 It should say CORRECTLY

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko What? No, my point is your `try except` should try to contain the least amount of code possible, or else you are left with a set of possible reasons why exceptsions are being thrown, and ideally, you want only *one*. So, more specifically, there are many reasons why the code in the `try` block could be throwing a `ValueError`, and we cannot narrow it down because any `ValueError` is being caught by the except clause.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'll remove it. But, do realize I am not that experienced with python.

Comment: So, a `ValueError` could be thrown because `int` is receiving the wrong invalid input, `.remove` is trying to remove something not in the list... you could at least print the error you are catching in the except block to make things easy.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I removed the extra code. It is a habit of mine to put more code than is needed. Sorry for you inconvenience. I won't do it again.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not receiving an error but I will print what happens when I run it.

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko that really wasn't the point of what I've been saying... As an aside, your approach of controlling your code by passing an argument to `Main()` and then checking a bunch of possibilities is pretty bad design. Why not just defined these things in different functions and call the appropriate function? You can even give it descriptive names...

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko yes, there *is* an error being thrown and caught, because your `except` block is executing!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `max() arg is an empty sequence` this is the error I think.

Comment: As far as the first snippet goes, I copy pasted it into my editor, removed the `return` statements of course as I don't have that block of code to run, removed the parts where `Deck` is called, also because I don't have that. And added the `YourFirstPick` input and created a random list of numbers `YourHand` just so I can have that block of code run. And it doesn't execute the except unless I put in something not a number. It means the issue is with your `Main()`

Comment: @Wright Do you want me to link the code so you can have a better look at it?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko Sure

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko Ok, then clearly it is coming from somewhere in the recursive stack. This is a great reason why you shouldn't use recursion to organize your control-flow like this. You are essentially reinventing a "goto" statement, and are getting spaghetti-code as a result. But clearly, somwehere, you are calling the `max` function on an empty list. That is your problem

Comment: @Wright I linked it in the problem. If you answer the question, refer to the code so people know what you are talking about.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I found it       `MaxList.append(int(YourTotalPick));` I didn't add the total to the list. However, it gave me another error on a different line.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the total to the list.

```
MaxList.append(int(YourTotalPick));
```